# Api call is failing and giving com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to newsapi.org not permitted

Tags: android, api, android-studio, android-volley

**Getting**

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext
> HTTP traffic to newsapi.org not permitted

Please help!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WfXK.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Comment: @YASAN No, i did tried those 4 options. So, like when i addded android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  the error changed to com.android.volley.AuthFailureError